# Hiding UI components when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

When a user clicks on one of the three button I need to apply the `Class` `active` (By default the first button is in '`active`' status).

How can I do this ?

```
<button class="nav-link active" > one </button>
<button class="nav-link " > two </button>
<button class="nav-link " > three</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following simple implementation.

Your html:

```
<button class="nav-link" [class.active]="isActiveFirst" (click)="isActiveFirst = true; isActiveSecond = false; isActiveThird = false"> one </button>
<button class="nav-link" [class.active]="isActiveSecond" (click)="isActiveFirst = false; isActiveSecond = true; isActiveThird = false"> two </button>
<button class="nav-link" [class.active]="isActiveThird" (click)="isActiveFirst = false; isActiveSecond = false; isActiveThird = true"> three</button>
```

Your ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isActiveFirst:boolean = true;
  isActiveSecond:boolean = false;
  isActiveThird:boolean = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bv1wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) about how you could do, and here is the code :

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of buttonsData">
    <button class="nav-link" (click)="setActive(btn.id)">{{btn.label}}</button>
</div>
```

ts:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private _elem: ElementRef) {}
  buttonsData = [
    { id: 0, label: "Link 1" },
    { id: 1, label: "Link 2" },
    { id: 2, label: "Link 3" }
  ];
  buttons;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.buttons = this._elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    this.setActive(0);
  }

  setActive(id) {
    console.log(this.buttons[id]);
    this.buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
    this.buttons[id].classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

css:

```
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

With this you just need to set a new item in `buttonsData` and everything is dynamic. Much better than a hard coded example I think.

Yould even remove the `id` value in `buttonsData` and simply handle an array of string and use the index to set the active class.